# DEPRECATION WARNING in rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, secret-key

My Rails version is Rails 4.0.13

I have my secret key in `config/initializers/secret_token.rb`, so I am not sure why it is still throwing this error.

> DEPRECATION WARNING: You didn't set config.secret_key_base. Read the upgrade documentation to learn more about this new config option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my secret_token.rb file, I changed the following:

```
API::Application.config.secret_key_base = ENV['SECRET_KEY']
```

to

```
API::Application.config.secret_key_base = 'SECRET_KEY'
```

and this seemed to fix the issue when I run it.